# How do I link gtk/gtk.h to my compiler in VSCode

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, gtk

I want to develop using gtk in VSCode. I am using C language. I am experiencing error as while compiling it giving an error of
`fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory`

My `c_cpp_properties.json` file

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:/Users/ac701/College/C C++",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-4.0",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/pango-1.0",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/harfbuzz",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/cairo",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/atk-1.0"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Note: all path exist and are correct. 
Note2: while hovering to at include part I seen which directory is needed by `gtk.h` I added them as shown in json file and after all that it started showing `gtk/gtk.h` is not a directory.

I copied an helloworld code from internet.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>



// Function to create the GUI
static void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data) {
    // Create a new window
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Hello World");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 200);

    // Create a label
    GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new("Hello, World!");

    // Add the label to the window
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), label);

    // Show all widgets
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Initialize GTK
    GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
    int status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);
    return status;
}
```

P.S. I am new to programming so I maybe getting something wrong. I have tried the solution of similar problem from Stackoverflow but it does not seem to work.

I tried similar solution from stack and also tried `cmake` thing but i just cant seem to make development environment to work.

I want to compile but it showing an error `gtk/gtk.h`

Comment: The file c_cpp_properties.json has nothing to do with this. You need to edit the tasks.json file to add the appropriate compiler arguments for whatever compiler you are using. Since you seem to be using g++ that would be `-Idir1 -Idir2 -Idir3` etc etc.

Comment: Then you would also need to add compiler arguments to link the GTK libraries. Sorry but I don't know anything about that for GTK

Comment: I'll be frank, if you are new to programming then using GTK is far too advanced. Concentrate on learning pure C++ first. Also if you are new to programming VSCode is probably not the best option either. It's complex, and there are easier alternatives which are just as good, if not better.

Comment: Why do you have the directories for both gtk3 and gtk4?

Comment: how are you building? do you have a build task config in tasks.json? are you using a "run code" command?